# Proving continuity of exp(x)

Tags: analysis, continuity, exponential-function

Well, my teacher went through a method of proving continuity of $\exp(x)$ which I don't like, so I tried to go about it a different way:

We have proved the following (which I use)

$\exp(x+y) = \exp(x)\exp(y)$

$\exp(0) = 1$

$\exp(x) \geq 1 + x \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

firstly, I prove it's continuous at $ x = 0$

for $x \leq 0$

$\exp(-x) = \dfrac{1}{\exp(x)}$

$\exp(-x) = 1 + (-x) + \dfrac{(-x)^2}{2!} +... = 1 + $ +ve terms so $\exp(-x) \geq 1$

so $\exp(x) \leq 1$

$\Rightarrow  1 + x \leq \exp(x) \leq 1$ then by sandwich theorem $\lim_{x\to0^-}\exp(x) = 1$

for $x \geq 0 $ $-x \leq 0 \Rightarrow 1 - x \leq \exp(-x) = \dfrac{1}{\exp(x)} \leq 1$ by subbing in (-x) to the above
therefore if $ 0 \leq x < 1 $ $\dfrac{1}{1-x} \geq \exp(x) \geq 1$ therefore $\lim_{x\to0^+}\exp(x) = 1$ therefore $\lim_{x\to 0} \exp(x) = 1$, I have a query at this point, can I consider $0 \leq x < 1$ and conclude $\lim_{x\to0+}\exp(x) = 1$?

Moving on, showing it is continuous for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$

assume a sequence $(x_n)$ is a seq. with $x_n \to c$ so $(x_n - c) \to 0 \Rightarrow \exp(x_n -c) \to 1$ (by the composition function theorem, and the step above)

$\exp(x_n) = \exp((x_n -c) + c) = \exp(x_n -c)\exp(c) \to \exp(c) $ how can I conclude from here?

Comment: You cannot use Taylor formula if you don't even know that the function is continuous...

Comment: That's funny I thought that too... but my teacher used the taylor formula in his proof too :s so I thought it was OK and I was missing something.

Comment: @user113494 : what definition of $\exp$ are you starting from?  Do you know it's the inverse of $\ln$, which is continuous and increasing?

Comment: It really depends on how the exp function was defined. One usual way is via the power series, from where continuity follows from general principles. -- In your approach, you can simplify some intermediate steps if you use $$1+x\le\exp(x)\le\frac1{1-x},$$ so you do not have to use one-sided limits.

Comment: We defined $\exp(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^n}{n!}$, we proved it converges absolutely $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, the lecturer starts his proof from this definition.

Comment: @StefanSmith We know the inverse, but we have proved nothing of it's inverse yet (we do later do it, but at this stage of the lecture we have not proved it).

Comment: That power series converges uniformly in any bounded interval $[-M,M]$, so it is continuous in  that interval as the uniform limit of continuous functions. Because this holds for all $M$, it is continuous everywhere. But have you done uniform convergences?

Comment: @user113494 : you should include the definition you're using of $\exp$ in your question, not just a comment, because it might be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the axiom of choice one can prove that there exists a function
$f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that $f(0)=1$, $f(a+b)=f(a)f(b)$, $f(x)\ge 1+x$ and $f$ is not continuous in any point. So the assumptions you have (apart from Taylor, which you shouldn't have), are not enough to conclude the proof.

However if you have defined (as I now see in the comments)
$$
\exp(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
you just have to notice that
$$
\exp(x) = 1 + x \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}
$$
whence for $x\to 0$
$$
|\exp(x) - 1| \le |x| \sum_{n=1}^\infty{|x|^{n-1}} \le |x| \frac{1}{1-|x|} \to 0
$$
and the continuity in $0$ is proven.

The continuity in a point $x\neq 0$ can be derived as you have described in the question.